# Complex Django Query to Create Dictionary

Tags: django, django-models

models.py

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateField()

class Result(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    place = models.IntegerField()
    person = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    score = models.IntegerField()
```

Event sample data:

```
id, name, date
1, 'event1', '2015-01-01'
2, 'event2', '2015-02-01'
3, 'event3', '2015-03-01'
```

Result sample data:

```
event_id, place, person, gender, score
1, 1, 'al', 'M', 25
1, 2, 'bob', 'M', 22
1, 3, 'cindy', 'F', 21
1, 4, 'doug', 'M', 20
2, 1, 'elen', 'F', 30
2, 2, 'frank', 'M', 28
2, 3, 'gord', 'M', 20
2, 4, 'helen', 'F', 19
```

I want to query this and get a dictionary containing the male and female winners (with scores) for each event:

```
winnersdict = {event_id: (mwinner, mscore, fwinner, fscore), ...}
```

In this case the resulting dictionary would be:

```
{1: ('al', 25, 'cindy', 21), 2: ('frank', 28, 'elen', 30). 3: (None, None, None, None)}
```

Right now I am doing it like this:

```
events = Event.objects.all().order_by('date')
winnersdict = {}
for e in events:
    femalewinner = Result.objects.filter(event_id=e.id, gender='F')[:1]
    if len(femalewinner) == 0:
        fwinner = None
        fscore = None
    else:
        fwinner = femalewinner[0].person
        fscore = femalewinner[0].score
    malewinner = Result.objects.filter(event_id=e.id, gender='M')[:1]
    if len(malewinner) == 0:
        mwinner = None
        mscore = None
    else:
        mwinner = malewinner[0].person
        mscore = malewinner[0].score
    winnersdict[e.id] = (mwinner, mscore, fwinner, fscore)
```

Surely there is a smarter way. I'm going to have thousands of events, looping through this way seems terrible. If it simplified things I would also be fine with generating a separate femalewinnersdict and malewinnersdict. I'm also fine (might even prefer) if we leave the None's out of the resulting dictionary, for this case I'm not interested in events that don't have results yet.

Any ideas?

Comment: maybe it is a better way to just get the winners for both genders? and then cast the result into whatever-structure you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try following query, it would give you male/female separately.

```
from django.db.models import Max

male_results = Event.objects.filter(result__gender='M') \
                            .annotate(max_score=Max('result__score')) \
                            .values('name', 'result__person', 'result__score')
```

Comment: it will give only males, won't it?

Comment: This works great. Is there any better way for me to convert that result into a dictionary than initializing an empty dictionary and looping through this result to set each key/value?

Comment: I thought it's already a dict like result, it's called `ValuesQuerySet`, you can use it just like a dictionary. If you really want to convert it to the dict, do `dict(male_results)`.